# How to add attribute name to JFactory::getEditor()

Tags: joomla, editor

I have a question about this method (JFactory::getEditor()):

I want to implement a Editor in my component (front) and I've done this:

```
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0', 'style'  => '1', 'layer'  => '0', 'table'  => '0', 'clear_entities'=>'0');
echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
```

I copied this from the Joomla documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor

But my question, how I can add the name attribute to pick it up on your controller when you click the submit form?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

In the OnDisplay () method's first parameter is the name of atribute name, I leave as eventually would, if anyone can serve data collection.

```
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0', 'style'  => '1', 'layer'  => '0', 'table'  => '0', 'clear_entities'=>'0');
echo $editor->display( '**ATTRIBUTE_NAME**', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
```

In controllers:

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('**ATTRIBUTE_NAME**', '');
```

If you want more information about the parameters, you can see Joomla file:  /plugins/editors/tinymce.php.

Comment: So have you figured this out? If so, please add a proper answer below and accept it ;)

Comment: Yes @Lodder, I found a solution for my problem by investigating, I let a new answer and I will accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution researching the library editor. The kind where the "OnDisplay" method is found is in the following path, in case you want to see all their parameters or other methods.

> **/plugins/editors/tinymce.php**

To use it do the following:

```
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0', 'style'  => '1', 'layer'  => '0', 'table'  => '0', 'clear_entities'=>'0');
echo $editor->display( 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
```

And to pick through a submit a form to do the following in their respective controllador:

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('ATTRIBUTE_NAME', '');
```

I hope that helps.